# Should I declare a mutable array/object as a const in ES2015?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If it was an immutable object, then I would have no doubt in declaring it as a const.
But in this case it's just a const reference to an object while the object is modified later in the code.

```
const styles = {};
...
styles.width = rect.width + 'px';
```

I'm afraid it will be confusing for developers reading this code.
It feels like `let` is more appropriate for objects that get mutated.